# unable to build android apk in ionic cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I ma trying to build apk file of my ionic android app with cordova. But every time its showing error on

```
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava
```

I want to create apk of 5.0 and set target 21 but still getting same error.

**Error:**

```
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaC:\xampp\htdocs\smaart\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:191: error: cannot find symbol
    getActivity().requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);

   symbol:   method requestPermissions(String[],int)
   location: class Activity
   C:\xampp\htdocs\smaart\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:197: error: cannot find symbol
    getActivity().requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);

   symbol:   method requestPermissions(String[],int)
   location: class Activity
   C:\xampp\htdocs\smaart\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\Cordo vaInterfaceImpl.java:202: error: cannot find symbol
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                                                   ^
      symbol:   variable M
      location: class VERSION_CODES
   C:\xampp\htdocs\smaart\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:204: error: cannot find symbol
        int result = activity.checkSelfPermission(permission);

     symbol:   method checkSelfPermission(String)
     location: variable activity of type Activity
   C:\xampp\htdocs\smaart\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaActivity.java:493: error: method does not override or implement a method froma supertype
   @Override
   ^

  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
```

FAILED
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
5 errors

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.235 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJava'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

Comment: Which android version you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First follow the steps Run Your SDK manager and download Android 6.0(API 23) Only SDK platform
The selected one in the Image[image]

Now check for path in your project..platforms\android\CordovaLib
Open project.properties and Check for

> target=android-23

Hope IT will build without error

Comment: i am using android version 5.0

Comment: Welcome now you can play with the android !!